# Ionic: onClick of ion-select, how to populate/refresh options?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to populate ion-select options onClick of that Field.
First time when i click select field, i get empty options pop up modal. second time i get populated options.

**.ts**

```
 loadLists() {
        this.car.getMakeList().then(res => {
            this.lists = res.makes;
        });
     }
```

**.html**

```
 <ion-item>
             <ion-label>Car Makes</ion-label>
             <ion-select (click)="loadLists()">
                 <ion-option *ngFor="let list of lists" value="{{ list.value }}">{{ list.label }}</ion-option>
             </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
```

How to populate or refresh the options after ionDidViewLoad?
I have tried

> ApplicationRef.tick(), NgZone.run(callback), 
>   ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()

to refresh option popup.

But nothing has worked for me.

Comment: Were you able to solve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that would be by

1. Disabling the select so that the click doesn't open it
2. Changing the styles so that it doesn't look like it is not enabled
3. Handling the click on the `ion-item` to load the options and open the select

---

Please take a look at **[working plunker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/load-option-when-opening-the-select)** to see it in action!

---

### home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <!-- Handle the click on the ion-item instead of the ion-select -->
    <ion-item (click)="onOpenSelect()">
      <ion-label>Car Makes</ion-label>
        <!-- Add the disabled property to the ion-select -->
        <ion-select disabled>
          <ion-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
           {{ option.label }}
          </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

### home.scss

```
page-home {
  /* Make the opacity to be 1 so it doesn't look like disabled */
  .item-select-disabled ion-label, 
  .select-disabled {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
}
```

### home.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Select } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styleUrls: [ './home.scss' ]
})
export class HomePage {

  public options = [];
  @ViewChild(Select) select: Select;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  public onOpenSelect(): void {
    console.log(`Options before opening: ${this.options.length}`);

    // We need to do this because otherwise the open()
    // event won't do anything since Ionic thinks the
    // component is disabled
    this.select.disabled = false;

    // Load the new options only if needed
    if(this.options.length === 0) {
      this.options = [
          { value: 1, label: 'Option 1' },
          { value: 2, label: 'Option 2' },
          { value: 3, label: 'Option 3' },
          { value: 4, label: 'Option 4' }
      ];
    }

    // Use a timeout to give some time to Angular
    // to update the view. The amount of time is not
    // important; it's just to run the code async
    setTimeout(() => {

      // Open the select
      this.select.open();

      console.log(`Options after opening: ${this.options.length}`);
    }, 100);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace the view did load function with

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
this.car.getMakeList().then(res => {
        this.lists = res.makes;
    });
}
```

Comment: No. I need to call that function on Onclick of that select field only.